# How to use HttpClient to upload a file to YouTube?

Tags: youtube, visual-studio-2012, microsoft-metro, httpclient

I have issue about upload file to Youtube

After survey the web page, I found the link https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_direct_uploading#Sending_a_Direct_Upload_API_Request
and has some finding to implement the Uploading.
But now I met questions list as below :

```
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + access_token);
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("GData-Version", "2.0");
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-GData-Key", "key=" + clientID);
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Slug", "video.wav");
//httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Content-Type", "multipart/related; boundary=\"f93dcbA3\"");
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Content-Length", "4141440");
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "close");
```

it will happen the exception and its reason is

**Misused header name. Make sure request headers are used with HttpRequestMessage, response headers with HttpResponseMessage, and content headers with HttpContent objects.**

So I change the way to

```
var requset = new HttpRequestMessage( new HttpMethod("post"), "https://gdata.youtube.com//feeds/api/users/default/subscriptions");

requset.Headers.Add("Host", "gdata.youtube.com");

requset.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + access_token);

requset.Headers.Add("GData-Version", "2.0");

requset.Headers.Add("X-GData-Key", "key=" + simpleKey);
string str = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><entry xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom\" xmlns:yt=\"http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007\"> <category scheme=\"http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/subscriptiontypes.cat\" term=\"channel\"/> <yt:username>GoogleDevelopers</yt:username></entry>";

StringContent cnt = new StringContent(str);

cnt.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/atom+xml");

cnt.Headers.ContentLength = 270;
```

But still without any effect, does anyone can give me some hint?

Thanks a lot

Mark